# Firefox add-on sdk packaging to xpi does not show exact icon and popup

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, firefox-22

I am developing an add-on for Firefox. My current problem is while using `cfx run` command add-on appears properly in navigation toolbar with icon and popup BUT when I package it using `cfx xpi` and install that xpi file then the icon and popup does not appear properly in navigation toolbar. What could be that cause?

This is the popup when I use `cfx run`
[image].

And this is the popup when I package to xpi and install it:
[image].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Fixed by [Serialize data content, fixes #1](https://github.com/Rob--W/browser-action-jplib/commit/12256529be943e4a7c52a5b8553fe21392cbaa4e):

> The cfx tool of Add-on SDK does not include any files in the
>   data directory of third-party modules in the built xpi file.
>
> This commit introduces a build script which serializes all files
>   in the data-dir to base64-encoded data-URIs, output in
>   browser-action-jplib-data.js
>
> This change does not require any changes in the public API.

---

This is a bug, being tracked at https://github.com/Rob--W/browser-action-jplib/issues/1.

The issue is caused by a bug in the [cfx tool](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/cfx-tool.html): `cfx xpi` does not add files from the `data` directory of third-party modules to the final `.xpi` file. I've reported this bug at https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=892977.

Comment: So I think we can not solve this issue until the next release of add-on SDK, am I correct Rob ?